# cannot save data to MongoDB with this assignment

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning MEAN stack with the book Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node.

I following the code and test everything, but I get a bug with no errors, in the book page 364, I cannot save salt and hash to MongoDB.

I use postman to test my code the same as the book, and I can get JWT in postman, but only can get _id, name, email and __v on MongoDB when I checked MongoDB with `db.users.find()` command.

the result like following listing:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57f5f1a91093e2650f427081"), 
"email" : "bb7@q.com", 
"name" : "bb7", 
"__v" : 0
```

I use arch Linux and MongoDB version is 3.2.9

and I guess setPassword methods cause the problem, but no error, weird.

the setPassword method is

```
userSchema.methods.setPassword = (password) => {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000,64,   'sha512').toString('hex');
};
```

and my entire code about register is

users.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
 var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
   type: String,
    unique: true,
   required: true
 },
  name: {
  type: String,
   required: true
  },
 hash: String,
  salt: String
});

 userSchema.methods.setPassword = (password) => {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
 this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000,64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) => {
  console.log('this salt  '+this.salt);
 // pbkdf2 params is password, salt, iterations, hashBytes, digest
 var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
  console.log('this hash '+this.hash);
 return this.hash === hash;
   };

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = () => {
  var expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

 return jwt.sign({
_id: this._id,
email: this.email,
name: this.name,
exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000) // Unix time in seconds
 }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
 };

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

authentication.js

```
  var passport = require('passport');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var User = mongoose.model('User');

 var sendJSONresponse = (res, status, content) => {
  res.status(status);
 res.json(content);
 };

 module.exports.register = (req, res) => {

  if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
   sendJSONresponse(res, 400, {
      'message': "All fields required"
   });
   return;
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;

  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

 user.save((err) => {
   var token;
   if(err) {
     sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
   } else {
     token = user.generateJwt();
     sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
      'token': token
     });
  }
 })
  }

 /** login */
 module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
   if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 400, {
     'message':'All fields required'
   });
  return;
 }

   passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    var token;

     if(err) {
      sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
      return;
   }

    if(user) {
       token = user.generateJwt();
     sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
       'token': token
      });
    } else {
      sendJSONresponse(res, 401, info); // info msg about why authentication failed
     }
 })(req, res);
  };
```

and whole code on github address is https://github.com/simonholmes/getting-MEAN/tree/chapter-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

- clone repo: `git clone git@github.com:simonholmes/getting-MEAN.git`
- checkout branch: `cd getting-MEAN; git checkout chapter-11`
- Set JWT secret: `export JWT_SECRET=secret`
- start app: `npm start`

And send register request:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/register -d "email=user@gmail.com&password=pass&name=user"
```

In response received:

```
{"token":"some token"}
```

Then checked mongo db:

```
mongo
> use Loc8r
> db.users.find()
```

Hash & salt are stored together with rest attributes. So not sure what problem you have here? If you want to get more attributes in response simply extend what is returned in `register` method in `authentication` controller:

```
user.save(function(err, user) {
  var token;
  if (err) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
  } else {
    token = user.generateJwt();
    sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
      "token" : token,
      "email": user.email,
      "id": user._id
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: no, I wanna save salt and hash in mongoDB, so could you tell me your system and versions of mongoDB and nodeJs? I very confused why cannot save data to mongoDB, and I fixed it half day, I feel setPassword function has problems, but not sure. and thank you @mkorszun

Comment: then, I recommend you that you start debugging; just add some console logs with generated hash and salt and check their values. Also check user object just before saving it - you should have answer if salt & hash are set.

Comment: I got it, the problem is arrow function in ES6 I thought it's OK in nodeJs so I changed it. thank you again.